# Python error in Qgis 2.14.0

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I'm trying to build virtual raster (catalog) following instructions from the documentation in QGIS.. It appears the following error in python code:

```
2016-04-17T12:13:07 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 160, in open_stack_dialog
            pypath=u"".join(u"<li>{}</li>".format(path) for path in sys.path))
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 160, in <genexpr>
            pypath=u"".join(u"<li>{}</li>".format(path) for path in sys.path))
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't know what it means...

Comment: do you have any non-English character in the QGIS and Python installation path?

Comment: no..the path has only english characters..

Comment: 0xCE is Î ([I with a circumflex](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x00CE/)) so it would be easy to miss this with some fonts.